# Async Usart IO_READ always null SAMD20J16

Tags: c, microcontroller, cortex-m, atmelstudio, usart

Fairly new to the Atmel software framework, usually use MPLab/PIC devices but for my project I needed to build a UART router capable of connecting 6 UART devices together so I chose a SAMD20J16 chip. So far iv'e configured the drivers using ATMEL start with USART HAL_ASYNC drivers for all USART modules.

Iv'e gotten the device to write to all 6 USART modules and have gotten the read interrupt to trigger but I am unable to read from the usart buffer. For now ive stripped it down to the minimal code possible to try and find out why it's not working, it's probably a simple oversight on my part, but Iv'e been searching the internet for 2 days and all the documentation I can find using the HAL_ASYNC drivers in ASF4 is flaky at best.

```
#include <atmel_start.h>



int main(void)
{
    int nRead=0;
    uint8_t rxPData;

    /* Initializes MCU, drivers and middleware */
    atmel_start_init();

    //DECLARE UART STRUCTURTES
    struct io_descriptor *uartD1;
    usart_async_get_io_descriptor(&USART_0, &uartD1);
    usart_async_enable(&USART_0);

    struct io_descriptor *uartP;
    usart_async_get_io_descriptor(&USART_1, &uartP);
    usart_async_enable(&USART_1);


    struct io_descriptor *uartD3;
    usart_async_get_io_descriptor(&USART_2, &uartD3);
    usart_async_enable(&USART_2);

    struct io_descriptor *uartD4;
    usart_async_get_io_descriptor(&USART_3, &uartD4);
    usart_async_enable(&USART_3);

    struct io_descriptor *uartS;
    usart_async_get_io_descriptor(&USART_4, &uartS);
    usart_async_enable(&USART_4);

    struct io_descriptor *uartD2;io_write(uartP, (uint8_t *) "UART P\r\n", 8);
    usart_async_get_io_descriptor(&USART_5, &uartD2);
    usart_async_enable(&USART_5);

    void uartP_callback(const struct usart_async_descriptor *const io_descriptor){
        if(usart_async_is_rx_not_empty(uartP)){
                io_write(uartP, (uint8_t *) "TEST P\r\n", 8);


                    nRead=io_read(uartP,&rxPData,6);

                    io_write(uartP,&rxPData,nRead);
        }



    }

    usart_async_register_callback(&USART_1, USART_ASYNC_RXC_CB, uartP_callback);

    while (1) {


    }     
}
```

Right now the observed behavior is anytime I send a UART packet it triggers the interrupt, and passes the IF rx_buffer_is_not_empty and sends back "TEST P\r\n". I added this line of code after some testing just to see if the interrupt was triggering.

However, no matter what input size i send to it it never transmits back any data that was sent to it.

Right now i'm simply trying to verify that I can receive and transmit on all usart ports, the final code won't have transmits inside the receive interrupts.

Comment: Tailback is called after every byte received and you can't read 6 bytes inside the call back. You end in the infinitive loop

Comment: @P__J__ I tried with specifying a single byte as well with the same results. by changing the io_read call to    nRead=io_read(uartP,&rxPData,1); it doesnt appear to be stuck in a loop as the program continues execution and I'm able to call on the interrupt again and process inside the main loop

Comment: @P__J__ Had another engineer take a look at my project files and he indicated that AtmelStart and Atmel Software Framework is missing a couple functions that are required for the HAL drivers. int32_t usart_async_enable_rx_done_irq and _usart_async_enable_rx_done_irq were never declared in the header files from ASF4 for the SAMD20 family.